# SwiftUI: How to make navigation bottom bar bigger

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, bottom-navigation-bar

I would like to put a big button in my navigationBottomBar.
[Just like in this view from Apple:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L81Eq.png)
[Or like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cIh7.png)

But if I just put a button in the navigationBottomBar like this:

```
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
            }
        }
```

The bottom bar doesn't get bigger and the bottom goes over the frame of the bottom bar.

How can I make the navigation bottom bar higher / bigger so that it looks like in the examples and the button fits in? Or are the buttons in the examples not placed in the bottom bar?
I would be very happy about help and I appreciate your time.
Have a great day

Comment: You are confusing the the bottom toolbar with the safe area. Essentially, the bottom toolbar is within the sage area. Trying playing with views in `.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) { your view here ]`.

Comment: @Yrb thank you for your answer but if I do this I don´t get this cool blur effect on the background. Any other ideas?

Comment: Add your own "cool blur effect". It is easy to do with `Material`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create an actual button inside your ToolbarItem/bottomBar? Something like this:

```
           NavigationView {
              Text("Content")
                 .navigationBarTitle("My App")
                 .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                       Button(action: {
                          // Handle button tap
                       }) {
                          Text("Big Button")
                             .fontWeight(.semibold)
                             .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                             .padding(.vertical, 12)
                       }
                       .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    }
                 }
           }
        }
        .padding()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
```